# To count number of 1's,0's,2's in a string in java

Tags: java, string

I'm new to the java string operations.

Let consider a string contains 0's,1's,2's like show below

```
String content = "0011221100";
```

You may ask me a question that why don't you store it in integer,Because in my case I should  have to use the string only.

The output be:

```
0's:4
1's:4
2's:2
```

How can I achieve it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you only need to search for `1's,0's,2's` 
so yo can try something like this :

```
 String content = "0011221100";
 int zeros = content.length() - content.replaceAll("0", "").length();
 int ones = content.length() - content.replaceAll("1", "").length();
 int twos = content.length() - content.replaceAll("2", "").length();
 System.out.println("0's:" + zeros);
 System.out.println("1's:" + ones);
 System.out.println("3's:" + twos);
```

Answer (score 5):

Loop through the chars of your `String` using [`toCharArray()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toCharArray%28%29).

For each char, check if it's a digit using [`Character.isDigit`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isDigit%28char%29)

Increment the number of occurences you found for this digit (you can use an `int` array of 10 slots and [`Character.getNumericValue`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#getNumericValue%28char%29) will be useful).

If you know that there is only digits in your `String`, step 2 is useless.

Answer (score 3):

You can try in this way.

```
    String content = "0011221100";
    Map<String,Integer> count=new HashMap<>();
    for(char i:content.toCharArray()){
        Integer index=count.get(String.valueOf(i));
       if(index!=null){
           count.put(String.valueOf(i),index+1);
       }else {
           count.put(String.valueOf(i),1);
       }
    }
    System.out.println(count);
```

Out put:

```
    {2=2, 1=4, 0=4}
```

Answer (score 3):

I recommend to try the following:

```
int[] amountOfNumbers = new int[3];

for(int i = 0; i < content.length(); i++){
    // Index 0 representing the number of 0s , Index 1 ..... and so on
    amountOfNumbers[content.charAt(i)-'0']++;
}
```

Now you can simple ask for the index and get the amount of numbers with value = index in the String.

I have to mention that the `int[] array` must have the same number of entries as there are different numbers in your string.

If you want any further information you can read the Countingsort article at Wikipedia:
[here](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Countingsort). My method is round about the same withour sorting it afterwards.

This method is alawys applicable if you know the range of numbers the string constist.

Comment: I like your solution very much! What about having a better loop: `for (char c : content.toCharArray()) { amountOfNumbers[c - '0']++; }`?

Comment: Of course you can use a foreach-loop, i just used a normal loop for the sake of readability (I think it's easier to get the idea of getting the i-th character and count the corresponding entry of the array). I think it's depending on the person which kind of for-loop he likes more ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void SymbolCounter( String source_ ) throws ParseException
{
    Map<Character, Integer> symbolCounter   = new HashMap<Character, Integer>();

    for( int i = 0 ; i < source_.length() ; ++i )
    {
        Character   symbol  = source_.charAt( i );
        Integer     counter = symbolCounter.get( symbol );

        if( null == counter )
        {
            counter = new Integer( 1 );

        }
        else
        {
            counter = counter + 1;

        }

        symbolCounter.put( symbol, counter );

    }

    Set<Character>  kyes    = symbolCounter.keySet();

    for( Character symbol : kyes )
    {
        Integer counter = symbolCounter.get( symbol );

        System.out.println( symbol.toString() + "'s:" + counter.toString() );

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this is reviving a dead horse, but there is now another option with java Streams.

```
"0011221100".chars().boxed().collect(
    Collectors.groupingBy(Character::getNumericValue, Collectors.counting()));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for (i=0;i<10;i++){
    reg=new RegExp("[^" + i + "]",'g');
    console.log(" " + i + "'s:" + content.replace(reg,"").length);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There you go:

```
void PrintCount(String content)
{
    int[] histogram = new int[10];
    for (int i=0; i<10; i++)
        histogram[i] = 0;

    for (char c : content.toCharArray())
    {
        if ('0' <= c && c <= '9')
            histogram[c-'0']++;
    }

    for (int i=0; i<10; i++)
        System.out.println(i+"'s:"+histogram[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you use java 8 or later releases, you can use this:

```
String temp = "0011221100";
Arrays.stream(temp.split(""))
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(s -> s, TreeMap::new, Collectors.counting()))
            .forEach((key, value) -> System.out.println(key + "'s:" + value));
```